Postgres shows wrong updated rows
I used dbeaver to run 3 queries:
select count(*)
from contacts
where id in (select contact_id from test_table)
-- 321621

delete contacts
using test_table
where contacts.id = test_table.contact_id;
-- Updated rows 168408

select count(*)
from contacts
where id in (select contact_id from test_table)
-- 0

I dont understand this part: Updated rows 168408, because in reality much more rows were deleted. Did i do something wrong while deleting?

Why does DBeaver say updated when it means deleted? Or is this a result of an update statement you executed in a different tab or window?

Best guess 168408 is the number of contact_id's involved.
